# Spring about findAll() function error in my project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have basicly user and role entities in my project.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="`User`")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = EAGER)
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users= new ArrayList<User>();

}
```

This is my controller class

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserResource {
    private final UserService userService;

     @GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers(){

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userService.getUsers());
    }
```

And this is my UserManager class

```java
@Service @RequiredArgsConstructor @Transactional @Slf4j
public class UserManager implements UserService {
    private final UserRepo userRepo;
    private final RoleRepo roleRepo;

     @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        log.info("Fetching all users {}" );
        return userRepo.findAll() ;
    }
}
```

When I request http://localhost:8080/api/users, I get wrong data like this

```
[{"id":5,"name":"Emirhan Ay","username":"emrhn1888","password":"1234","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_USER","users":[{"id":5,"name":"Emirhan Ay","username":"emrhn1888","password":"1234","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_USER","users":[{"id":5,"name":"Emirhan Ay","username":"emrhn1888","password":"1234","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_USER","users":[{"id":5,"name":"Emirhan Ay","username":"emrhn1888","password":"1234","roles":[{"id"}]}]}]}]
```

But the data saved in the db is like this
[image: MY DATA]

Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 'circular dependency'. User has roles, the role has users, etc. You should probably first map entities to DTOS and then maybe add `@JsonManagedReference` or `@JsonBackReference`.

Or you can simply put `@JsonIgnore` on `private List<User> users= new ArrayList<User>();`